# Server Application Unavailable

Tags: exception, asp.net-2.0

I am using visual studio 2005. When I debug and reached at exception point. I got following error dialouge.

[message screenshot](http://www.uploadgeek.com/share-C8C8_4AC36C6B.html)

When I click No, I got following error page.

The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request.

**Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.**

I also checked the eventvwr log and it says:

**aspnet_wp.exe  (PID: 3584) stopped unexpectedly.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.**

Please help me.

Comment: put the image somewhere else, can't see it

Comment: The error sounds familiar though, some unhandled exception that killed the app

Comment: That's still a hotlink directly to the image. Can you send us to an ImageGeek page where it can be viewed, or can you Flickr it (or some other site that does allow hotlinking)?

Comment: image link is added now.

Comment: oops, didn't see your screen shot. Debug it and provide us with more info.

Comment: What does the entry in the event log say?

Comment: event viewr is showing follwoing entry.
aspnet_wp.exe (PID: 3584) stopped unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image (hotlinking to that site isn't allowed), but I'm guessing that when you hit "No", you're telling ASP.NET that you don't want to debug the exception, so it's letting it bubble up to the browser, which shows you the "Webserver unavailable" that you're seeing. If you debug your error, what do you get?

Also, please fix your image so we can see your dialog box.

Comment: please check. i added page link.